Why my own mail server not sending mails to another domain?
I am configuring my own mail server using iRedMail on a self-hosted setup. The server works fine for sending emails to local domains, but I am unable to send messages to external domains such as Gmail. After checking the logs, I noticed repeated errors related to connection timeouts and network issues on port 25.
Here are some snippets from my logs:
connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.184.27]:25: Connection timed out  
connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0b::1a]:25: Network is unreachable  
connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable  
status=deferred (connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)  
connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4004:c1f::1a]:25: Network is unreachable  
connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4004:c1f::1b]:25: Network is unreachable  
connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.179.27]:25: Connection timed out  
connect to aspmx.l.google.com[142.250.31.27]:25: Connection timed out

When I test port 25 using Telnet: telnet public_ip 25
Questions:

How can I confirm if my cloud provider is blocking port 25?
If port 25 is blocked, what are the alternative ways to configure my mail server to send emails?
Are there any specific troubleshooting steps I can follow to verify and resolve this issue?


You don't mention anything about AWS or EC2 in your question, but you have tagged the question with amazon-web-services. Are you attempting to host a mail server on an AWS EC2 instance?

Is your code running on an Amazon EC2 instance? See: Remove port 25 restriction for Email Sending from EC2 and Lambda | AWS re:Post | AWS re:Post
